# Сайт, опрашивающий чужой ресурс

Tags: javascript

Я ничего подобного раньше не делал. Пытаюсь разобраться с нуля. Задача такая: написать код, который будет получать по таймеру информацию с чужого интернет-сайта. Про то, как устроен их сервер я ничего не знаю. Поэтому хотелось бы узнать, по какому алгоритму действовать? С помощью чего узнавать, как оно работает и какой запрос мне надо посылать? Реализовывать буду на javascript.

Теперь о том, что я уже попробовал сделать.
Есть [сайт для подачи заявки](https://www.visaservices.co.in/Finland-visa-application/AppScheduling/AppScheduling.aspx?P=PcqAqEGdf4OMbJ1CZgKHSUN3Je9Uumiy6NGhvmhMab7phBf7hKlWsBQNrNze6jyj+86S93yLA0yGdiqvwB5yZg==). Пользователь выбирает пункт Consulate General of Finland, St. Petersburg и нажимает "Отправить". Затем из элемента select пользователь выбирает цель визита, допустим, Tourism. В момент изменения выбранного пункта, появляется надпись: либо о том, что нет доступных дат (как чаще всего и бывает), либо выводит доступную дату. У этого элемента select есть такое свойство:

```
onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$plhMain$cboVisaCategory\',\'\')', 0)"
```

Во вкладке Network панели разработчика видно, что отправляется post-запрос. В нём большую часть занимает так называемая "Form Data", содержание которой - нечитаемое сочетание символов. И еще: у запроса есть cookie, какой-то ASP_session. А также есть сайт, на котором такая задача уже сделана: http://visastat.ru. Собственно, узнав про него, я и решил в учебных целях разобраться, как это работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё же не совсем понятна цель. Ну да ладно.

Если бы речь шла о том, как делать периодический опрос своего ресурса, то тут надо использовать AJAX. На эту тему очень много информации. Начать можно, например, с Ajax In Action ([AJAX в действии](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2760949/)). Она уже начинает устаревать, но всё ещё актуальна и для обучения сгодится.

Когда же речь идёт об опросе чужого ресурса, то тут AJAX не годится. Главная причина - security policy, которое не позволяет делать запросы к чужим ресурсам. Выхода в данной ситуации два: проксирование на вашем сервере, либо использование скрытого iframe. При первом подходе на клиентской стороне вы сможете использовать обычный AJAX. Также у вас будет больше контроля за процессом. Второй путь не требует ничего от вашей серверной стороны, но вызовет ряд сложностей по управлению загрузкой в iframe в разных браузерах. Среди проблем, например, невозможность обнаружить неожиданный обрыв связи во время загрузки данных.

Учитывая разные плюсы и минусы, вам следует выбрать удобный для вас путь.

В данном случае, у вас также имеется некий ресурс и вам надо понять, что именно надо туда передать, чтобы всё заработало и надо понять, что он вернёт в качестве ответа. К сожалению, может оказаться, что просто нереально узнать это. Если не удастся найти никакой документации о том, что же там происходит, то можно применить реверс-инжиниринг: попытаться разгадать, что же значат передаваемые сведения в разных случаях. Можно также попытаться отформатировать JavaScript того сайта, который уже умеет работать с этими данными и попытаться разобраться в нём. В целом, я не уверен, что подобные раскопки - полезное времяпровождение и образовательный эффеки будет минимальным.

Comment: Посмотрите, я в конце сообщения написал, что кто-то всё-таки релизовал подобное: сайт http://visastat.ru. Если говорить о цели, то смысл в том, что финскую визу можно получить бесплатно в консульстве и за 21евро в визовом центре. Но в консульство надо записаться через интернет сайт, см.ссылку. Запись открывается на несколько минут в день, макс.период - полчаса. Но один умный программист написал ресурс, который отслеживает, открыта ли регистрация, а также имеет историю регистраций. Много людей посещает сайт, чел разместил рекламу и радуется.

Comment: А я разве говорил, что это невозможно? Просто если данные совсем нечитаемые, то без определённой подготовки и интуиции вам не раскрыть кодировку.

Comment: Печально. Поxоже, всё очень сложно.

Comment: С другой стороны, если всегда всего бояться, то вы так и будете обходить интересные задачи стороной. Так что попробовать стоит, но на надежду не полагайтесь.